# How to connect to a third party VPN from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpn, google-kubernetes-engine

**Requirements**

1. I am trying to connect to a third party VPN from my back end on Google Cloud Platform.
2. Since my IP has to be whitelisted by the third party, the source IP for all requests must be a single static IP address.

**My plan so far...**

Currently I plan to run a Kubernetes service that runs as a "proxy", such that the service is connected to the VPN and the rest of my back end can send requests to the proxy. Requests from my back end to the proxy service should obviously not run via the VPN, but requests from the proxy service to the third party should run on the VPN.

**The challenge**

I know how to reserve an IP address, but I don't even know where to begin to set up a VPN client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!